# Outlining algorithm

Tags: algorithm, image-manipulation

What good algorithm can I use to outline an image? currently I go pixel by pixel, if its transparent and there is a pixel around it that is not transparent, it is set to black.
This works well for aliased images, but not for anti-aliased images. for anti-aliased images it just looks like the image is surrounded by 0.5px transparent line and then black border around that. and the black border itself is not anti-aliased.
What algorithm can I use to outline an anti-aliased image with anti-aliased 1px line?

Answer (score 0):

You may have some luck using the opacity of the original image to determine the opacity for your outline:

For each pixel, if the pixel is partially transparent, make it black, but use the same transparency as the original image. If the pixel is fully transparent or fully opaque, leave it as is.

Comment: that will create some sort of 0.5px black line. it will also not work for vertical and horizontal line that don't have transparency.

Comment: That's true. You will probably have to look into some more sophisticated image processing algorithms to get what you want. I know of [edge detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection), but that finds *all* edges, not just the exterior ones.